# Can I model laminar incompressible fluid flow and heat transfer in MATLAB's PDE toolbox?

Tags: matlab, pde, finite-difference, fluid-dynamics

I have a system of PDEs in cylindrical coordinates that needs to be solved:
1. Continuity equation
2. Incompressible Navier stokes ( in r & z coordinates)
3. Heat transfer equation with both conduction and convection terms

Is it possible to solve these equations using PDE toolbox?

This is the link from the MATLAB website I referred to:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/equations-you-can-solve.html

However, I do not think my equations would fit into this form.

Is discretization by the finite difference method a better way? 
Is application of the SIMPLE algorithm by Patankar necessary?

Comment: I don't know about the toolbox, but in general solving a 2D PDE in Matlab can be rather slow.  Some important questions relevant to this: compressible or incompressible?  What Reynolds number?  Laminar or turbulent?

Comment: Incompressible Newtonian fluid and laminar flow

Comment: Thanks; it's best if you edit the question to include that kind of information.  I've done so for you.

Comment: At first glance, I think the answer is no, since you can't fit the convective term into that form.

Comment: What if the convective term were to be neglected? Do the other equations fit into that form? Thanks for your help

Comment: The f-term in the supported equation is general enough to accommodate the convective term. What is the Reynolds number for your flow?

Comment: Very low. Around 5

Comment: Instead of using PDE toolbox, I thought of discretizing these equations but now I have four non linear equations with boundary conditions:  So now I have 4 non linear equations with 4 variables(u,v,T,f) such that: f1(u,v)=0 f2(u,v,f)=0 f3(u,v,f)=0 f4(u,v,f,T)=0

u-Axial velocity v-Radial velocity T-temperature f-liquid fraction (my problem involves solidification of metal)

Can I solve these using fsolve?

Answer (score 1):

The cylindrical coordinate form of PDE equations are not available as default equations with the PDE Toolbox, but should be able to be entered as a custom PDE equation form.

Alternatively, both the Navier-Stokes equations and heat transfer (heat conduction with convection/advection) is also available for MATLAB as pre-defined (axisymmetric) PDE equations with the [FEATool Multiphysics toolbox](https://www.featool.com).

Answer (score -1):

There is a [book](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319168739) on the finite volume method (FVM), which is widely used to solve flow problems. Aside from presenting the theory behind the method, the authors demonstrate the finite volume method on a Matlab-based FVM code and on OpenFOAM, which is a C++ library implementing the finite volume method.